# whether azure functions can be used to receive messages from IBM MQ when a message is received in Queue

Tags: c#, azure-functions, ibm-mq

could you please guide on whether azure functions in c# can be used to receive messages from IBM MQ when a message is received in Queue

Comment: This was already asked today (the question is already removed, but it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106060/need-to-use-azure-functions-to-receive-messages-from-ibm-mq-when-a-message-is-re)). And the answer is the same: stackoverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service.

Comment: Please do some research before posting any question to SO and ask question based on the SO guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can use Azure Logic App with MQ Connector. Microsoft Connector for MQ sends and retrieves messages stored in an MQ Server on-premises, or in Azure. This connector includes a Microsoft MQ client that communicates with a remote IBM MQ server across a TCP/IP network. [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq) is a starter guide to use the MQ connector.

The MQ connector includes the following actions. There are no triggers.

- Browse a single message without deleting the message from the IBM MQ Server
- Browse a batch of messages without deleting the messages from
  the IBM MQ Server
- Receive a single message and delete the message
  from the IBM MQ Server
- Receive a batch of messages and delete the
  messages from the IBM MQ Server
- Send a single message to the IBM MQ
  Server

Note that the MQ Connector does not have any triggers. So, use another trigger to start your logic app, such as the [Recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence).

Comment: The OP has asked this question twice today; best not to encourage this multi-post behavior when posting off-topic questions (the 1st post has already been deleted as off-topic). And this is more of a documentation request question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Agreed